# Connection failed to mysql database after upgrade to version 8 AWS

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, server, amazon-rds

I am experiencing an issue after the MYSQL upgrade from version 5.7 to 8 on **AWS RDS**. Before the upgrade, my server used to work properly but immediately after getting the database updated to version 8, it appears to be broken. The error is as follows:

```
Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
```

I am fairly new to MYSQL and I could not find a suitable online solution to solve this issue. Ideally, I would like to know if there is a proper way to view an "in-depth" log about any exceptions causing this as it is the only error message I am getting. Or perhaps, I am looking for some guidance about what might cause this failure in the database connection, please.

I am lost at this point.

Your help will be much more appreciated!

I wish to thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check database name or database name, username and password toghether.

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
mysql> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
```

Check best solution MySQL 8 connection URI syntax and options.

```
protocol//[hosts][/database][?properties]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve this issue by just updating the mysql-connector. For my project, I am using Clojure and I am using this dependency:

```
[mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.x.x"]
```

Updating to version 8.x.x solve the issue.